# Issues with SQL query using SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql

The relevant part of my database schema looks like this (Ruby on Rails migration code, but should be easy to read):

```
create_table "team_memberships" do |t|
  t.integer  "team_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "users" do |t|
  t.integer "id"
  t.string  "slug"
end

create_table "performance_points" do |t|
  t.integer "id"
  t.integer "user_id",
  t.date    "date",
  t.integer "points",
  t.integer "team_id"
end
```

I want a query that returns a list of users sorted by the total amount of performance points they have received since a certain date. Note that one "performance_points" row does not equal one point, we need to sum the "points"

The query I have so far looks like this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.slug, SUM(pp.points) AS total
FROM users u
JOIN performance_points pp ON pp.user_id = u.id
JOIN team_memberships tm ON tm.team_id = pp.team_id AND tm.user_id = pp.user_id
WHERE (pp.date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221')
GROUP BY pp.id, u.id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 50
```

The first three results are:

```
"id","slug","total"
32369,"andreas-jensen-9de10dec-0f88-427f-b135-62cebea611c8",245
23752,"kenneth-kjaerstad",95
34179,"marius-mork-rydal",93
```

To check that results are correct I count the points for each user. However the second one seems to be wrong. I run this query with Kenneth's id:

```
SELECT SUM(performance_points.points)
FROM performance_points
WHERE performance_points.user_id = 23752
  AND (date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221')
```

I get: `84`. Looking at all Kenneth's performance points with:

```
SELECT performance_points.points
FROM performance_points
WHERE performance_points.user_id = 23752
  AND (date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221')
```

We get:

```
"points"
-10
1
-2
95
```

-10 + 1 - 2 + 95 is indeed 84 so I dunno whats going on with the first query. Why is the total 95?

I'm running PostgreSQL version 9.3.5

Comment: Are all of the performance points rows for the same team_membership?

Comment: In the case with this user they are, but that might not always be the case. Users can be on multiple teams and get points from each.

Comment: Just replace in the your original query `select ...` to `select *` and remove `group by` clause and, I am sure, you will find the problem.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't' see it. I posted my results here https://gist.github.com/davidpdrsn/c0f72640ed1af15ae743

Comment: BTW, you are grouping your results by user id and performance_points id: `GROUP BY pp.id, u.id`. Is it right? or it is just mistyping? Grouping by pp.id you will have separate points, not the sum of them.

Comment: Please edit example input, output & desired output plus table constraints into your question. Read about MCVEs in the help center.

Comment: Why are you joining with team_memberships? Is not performance_points (user_id,team_id) a FK into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that there actually wasn't a problem with the query, but with the data. There were some users who were on multiple teams more than once and that have issues.

Answer (score 2):

If `slug` is unique per user:

```
SELECT u.id, u.slug, SUM(pp.points) AS total
FROM users u
JOIN performance_points pp
ON u.id = pp.user_id
WHERE pp.date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221'
GROUP BY u.id, u.slug
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Otherwise you can't `SELECT` `slug` because it's not a grouping column, so there are multiple values of it in each group. You want to `GROUP BY user_id` in `performance_points` to get `total` per `user_id` then `JOIN` with `users` to get `slug`s.

```
SELECT id, slug, total
FROM users
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(points) AS total
    FROM performance_points
    WHERE date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221'
    GROUP BY user_id) t
ON id = user_id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 50
```

(It's not clear why you are `JOIN`ing with `team_membership`. Presumably `performance_points (user_id,team_id)` is a foreign key into it, ie all such pairs are already in it.)

Answer (score 2):

I took your query and added a filter to limited to a single user. You should now see four rows for user kenneth-kjaerstad:

```
SELECT u.id, u.slug, SUM(pp.points) AS total
FROM
    users u
    JOIN performance_points pp ON pp.user_id = u.id
    JOIN team_memberships tm ON tm.team_id = pp.team_id AND tm.user_id = pp.user_id
WHERE pp.date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221' and u.id = 23752
GROUP BY pp.id, u.id
```

The problem was that the sort pushed all the other rows way down this list and you never saw that there were three others for him besides the one at the top of the ranking.

The reason is that your grouping is wrong as you just want a total per user. `pp.id` should in fact be unique for every row in your results and it's pointless to have a group by on that column at all.

Also I'll note that there doesn't seem to be a purpose in your join to the `team_memberships` table unless you need to guarantee that a team membership exists for each pairs of user and team ids from the points table. Here's the fix:

```
SELECT u.id, min(u.slug) as slug, SUM(pp.points) AS total
FROM
    users u
    JOIN performance_points pp ON pp.user_id = u.id
    JOIN team_memberships tm ON tm.team_id = pp.team_id AND tm.user_id = pp.user_id
WHERE pp.date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221'
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER by total desc
```

This answer is essentially equivalent to @philipxy and @Hambone's. As you can see it's not strictly necessary to use some of the constructs they chose. Hopefully my explanation of what went wrong is helpful whichever approach you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all of your data it's a little hard to guess, but maybe a CTE to pre-process the performance points would do it:

```
with pp_totals as (
  select user_id, sum (points) as points
  from performance_points
  where date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221'
  group by user_id
)
SELECT
  u.id, u.slug, pp.points AS total
FROM
  users u
  JOIN pp_totals pp ON pp.user_id = u.id
  JOIN team_memberships tm ON tm.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY pp.points DESC
limit 50
```

If this doesn't do it, can you create a SQL Fiddle and post it to your question?

Comment: But why team_memberships? (Hopefully we'll hear more.)

Comment: @philipxy -- I noticed that as well, but I rolled with it.  I did alter the join, based on some assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Try below query and let us know the answer, if it works :

```
SELECT u.id, u.slug, SUM(pp.points) AS total
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (select user_id,date,team_id, SUM(points) as points from performance_points group by user_id,date,team_id) pp ON pp.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN (select team_id, user_id from team_memberships group by team_id, user_id) tm ON tm.team_id = pp.team_id AND tm.user_id = pp.user_id
WHERE (pp.date > '2015-08-02 13:57:14.042221')
GROUP BY u.id, u.slug
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 50
;
```

Comment: That gives an error: "ERROR: column pp.team_id does not exist". If I add `team_id` to the `select` of the first `inner join` I get: "ERROR: column “performance_points.team_id” must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Corrected .Please check .